# Custom Class Objects over WCF

Tags: wcf

I am testing a few things over the weekend and I've make the following custom object.

Person

```
  int Age;
  string HairColor;
```

for time's sake I'm not showing the get/set code here but in the class, it exists. The class works just fine in a Winforms app.

Now what I want to do is take that exact same class (which resides in a DLL) and allow a WCF service to return it to a client.

How do I do this? Can I just reference the DLL with the WCF service or do I need to do something special?

Comment: why not try it and find out? You'd already know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize that class so it can be used as an argument in a WCF service call, you have to:

- either use the "implicit" serialization that WCF has since .NET 3.5 SP1 - it works much in the same way as the XML serializer; all public properties are serialized

or if you require more control over what gets serialized:

- you need to decorate your class(es) with `[DataContract]` attributes (for the class level) and decorate each item you want to have serialized (public or not, property or field) with a `[DataMember]` attribute

The explicit decoration with the [DataContract]/[DataMember] attributes has some clear advantages:

- you can define an XML namespace for your serialized data classes
- you can define which fields and/or properties (public or not) you want to have serialized
- you can rename a property in serialization, e.g. you can give it another name in the data structure that will be sent from client to server
- you can control the order in which the fields and properties are serialized
- you don't need to provide a parameter-less constructor for deserialization

Of course, there's no free lunch - it means you have to go and decorate all the classes you want to use as WCF method parameters and/or return types.

Comment: Well, actually it's being returned from WCF to the client, the client isn't sending it to WCF. Although this might happen in the future.

Comment: @Philip: doesn't make a difference - whether it's being sent from the server to the client or the other way around - in order for WCF to know how to serialize the data, a DataContract is very much needed. If you already have .NET classes, and all the properties that need to be sent across are public properties on your class, then you should be fine - just reference your existing DLL and get going!

Answer (score 0):

create a `public` class for the WCF `[ServiceContract]`

```
public Person{

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string HairColor { get; set;}
}
```

This should be then be serialized automatically.

Comment: I'm assuming I need to make a dedicated class file for WCF then right? I can't use the DLL that was created for the WinForms?

Comment: Simply create a class library to use for the classes shared between the two.

Comment: Right, I already have a class library being used by the client app now. So I just reference that DLL within WCF and go from there, yes?